# Why is my data being displayed differently on my interface?

Tags: java

As part of an assignment question I had to create an application that involved a client and server. The client allows the user to connect to the database and upon connection and ID number is selected from the combobox and the relevant information is called from the database. The information is first stored in an array and then displayed in the relevant textfields. Although I do know an array for something like this is illogical it was a requirement in the assignment so I had to use it. The server will display when it was started and that a client is connected to it. The client interface will receive a similar response from the server and display it. When the user selected "Send to Server" it will send and display the information on the server and also on the client interface. The images below show how this works and what the error is:

When the user connects the information of a person is displayed in the textfields: [image]

When the user clicks "Send to server the information is displayed on both the client and server interfaces as shown below (This is how it must work):[image]

When the next person is selected on the client interface, the information is shown: [image]

However when I select "Send to Server" it will display the details correctly on the server interface but all it displays on the client interface is that the user is connected to the server, the client number and the date as illustrated below:
[image]

But when I do the same process with a third person, it will display the current person's details in the server and the previous person's details on the client interface as shown below: [image]

I have gone through the entire coding of both interfaces but I cannot find the problem (based on my coding knowledge). My question therefore is what could be causing this problem that I demonstrated in the screenshots and how do I fix it in the coding?

Here is the socket coding in the server class (th rest is just GUI coding):

```
try
        {
            //creates the server socket
            ServerSocket ssocket = new ServerSocket(8100);

            while(true)
            {
                //accepts the socket connection
                Socket ssocket2 = ssocket.accept();
                //increments the client number
                clientNum++;
                //creates the task class
                ProcessClients pc = new ProcessClients(ssocket2,clientNum);
                Thread thread = new Thread(pc);
                //starts the thread
                thread.start();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There was a problem connecting to the server", "SERVER ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
```

Here is the coding for the ProcessClients class in the server interface:

```
class ProcessClients implements Runnable
{
    //declares the socket
    private Socket s;
    //declares the client number
    private int clientNumber;
    //declares the array for the User object
    ArrayList<User> array = new ArrayList<>();

    //constructor
    public ProcessClients(Socket soc, int clientNum)
    {
        this.s = soc;
        clientNumber = clientNum;

    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            //declares DataInputStream for retrieving data
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream()); 
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());            
            //message to be displayed showing client number and date of connection
            String connected = "\nConnected to Client Number: " + clientNumber + "\nConnection Date: " + new Date();
            jtaResults.append(connected);
            while(true)
            {
                //message from the server responding to connection with client number, time and date
                String response = "\nSERVER RESPONSE:\nConnected to server:\nClient Number: " + clientNumber + "\nConnection Date: " + new Date(); 
                dos.writeUTF(response);
                //input stream for the userID
                int userID = dis.readInt();
                //input stream for the lastName
                String lastName = dis.readUTF();
                //input stream for the firstName
                String firstName = dis.readUTF();
                //input stream for the age
                int age = dis.readInt();
                //creates user object
                User use = new User(userID, firstName, lastName, age);
                //Mutator methods to set user objects
                use.setuserID(userID);
                use.setlastName(lastName);
                use.setfirstName(firstName);               
                use.setage(age);
                //add object to array list
                array.add(use);
                //confirmation message regarding data received from client
                String confirm = "\n SERVER RESPONSE:\nData received from client number: " + clientNumber +
                        "\nUser ID: " + userID + "\nFirst Name: " + firstName + "\nLast Name: " + lastName + 
                        "\nAge: " + age + "\nDate received: " + new Date();
                dos.writeUTF(confirm);
                //displays the client number in the text area
                jtaResults.append("\n\n Message from client number: " + clientNumber + "\n");
                //displays the user ID in the text area
                jtaResults.append("User ID: " + use.getuserID() + "\n");
                //displays the first name in the text area
                jtaResults.append("First Name: " + use.getfirstName() + "\n");
                //displays the last name in the text area
                jtaResults.append("Last Name: " + use.getlastName() + "\n");
                //displays the age in the text area
                jtaResults.append("Age: " + use.getage());
                jtaResults.append("\nDate received: " + new Date());
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There was a problem retrieving the data", "SERVER ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } 
    }
```

Here is the coding for the client class (GUI coding excluded):

```
public ClientApp()
    {
        InterfaceProperties();
        try
        {
            Socket csocket = new Socket("localhost", 8100);
            input = new DataInputStream(csocket.getInputStream());
            output = new DataOutputStream(csocket.getOutputStream());
            String sresponse = input.readUTF();
            jtaResults.append(sresponse);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There was a problem connecting to the server", "SERVER ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    //method for connecting to the database
        private void ConnectDB()
        {
            String query = "Select * from studentinfo";
            try
            {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
               //connection
                Connection conn = (Connection)
                        //root and username and password for access to the database
                DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentdb","root","");

                //create the statement that will be used
                Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    int userID = rs.getInt("userID");
                    cboIDNums.addItem(userID);

                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "An error occured while trying to connect to the database", "CONNECTION ERROR!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

        }

        public int idValue;

        private void searchDB(int ID)
        {
            try
            {
                idValue = ID;
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
               //connection
                Connection conn = (Connection)
                        //root and username and password for access to the database
                DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentdb","root","");

                //create the statement that will be used
                PreparedStatement stmt=conn.prepareStatement("Select * from studentinfo where userID = '" + ID + "'");

                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                java.sql.ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
                int numColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();

                rs.first();
                int rowcount = 0;
                do
                {
                    rowcount++;
                } 
                while (rs.next());

                rs.first();
                int rowindex = 0;
                Object array2D[][] = new Object[rowcount][];
                do 
                {
                    array2D[rowindex] = new Object[numColumns];
                    for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) 
                    {
                        array2D[rowindex][i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);
                    }


                    rowindex++;
                } 
                while (rs.next());
                jtfLastName.setText(array2D[0][2].toString());
                jtfFirstName.setText(array2D[0][1].toString());
                jtfAge.setText(array2D[0][3].toString());


            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There was a problem retrieving data", "SERVER ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }

        //declarng a click function
        boolean clicked = true;

        //method for the action listener
        private void btnConnectOptionActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
        {
            if(clicked)
            {
                //changes the butten text from 'Connect' to 'Disconnect'
                btnConnectOption.setText("Disconnect");
                clicked = false;
                ConnectDB();
            }
            else
            {
                //changes the button text from 'Disconnect' to 'Connect'
                btnConnectOption.setText("Connect");
                clicked = true;

                //resets the text fields
                jtfAge.setText("");
                jtfFirstName.setText("");
                jtfLastName.setText("");
                //resets the combo box
                cboIDNums.removeAllItems();
                try
                {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
               //connection
                Connection conn = (Connection)
                        //root and username and password for access to the database
                DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentdb","root","");
                //closes the database connection
                conn.close();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The database does not want to disconnect", "DISCONNECTION ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        }

        //method for the action listener
        private void btnSendToServerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
        {
            try
            {
                int userIDs = Integer.parseInt(cboIDNums.getSelectedItem().toString());
                String lastNames = jtfLastName.getText();
                String firstNames = jtfFirstName.getText();            
                int ages = Integer.parseInt(jtfAge.getText());

                output.writeInt(userIDs);
                output.writeUTF(lastNames);
                output.writeUTF(firstNames);
                output.writeInt(ages);
                output.flush();
                jtfFirstName.setText("");
                jtfLastName.setText("");
                jtfAge.setText("");
                String receive =  input.readUTF();
                jtaResults.append(receive);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "An error occured loading data from text fields!\nFields empty!", "ERROR!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }

        private void cboIDNumsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
        {
            try
            {
                idValue = Integer.parseInt(cboIDNums.getSelectedItem().toString());
                searchDB(idValue);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Database disconnected", "DISCONNECT SUCCESSFUL", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It smells to me as a buffer flushing effect. Try to add a `dos.flush()` after the last call to `dos.write*` in the `ProcessClients.run`method.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and it did not fix the problem.